# Silverlight version of StyleSnooper

Tags: .net, silverlight, controltemplate

To view the default style/control templates for built-in WPF controls, [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) is an invaluable tool.

However I can't seem to find a version that works for Silverlight controls.

Does such a tool exist, or do I just need to do something different with StyleSnooper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a tool, but all default styles and templates are available in the Silverlight documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's handy (and what I ended up using) but there may be other controls in a DLL that you want to see the styles for.  Such a tool would still be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If I need a controls default style, I normally use Blend to generate it for me. Also, you can view styles of controls using SilverlightSpy.